# Prevent from committing code that didn't pass the unit tests (eclipse & Perforce)

Tags: unit-testing

We want to verify that there are no unit tests for the committed code that fails before allowing the developers to commit.
Do you know any tool that will help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against doing this, because in practice there *are* times when you want to allow developers to submit code that does not pass all its unit tests. Also, consider that developers might try to work around the restriction by deleting unit tests, or by not writing them in the first place.

And how could the tool determine that all unot tests passed? It would have to build the code and run the unit test-suite. A fault in the build environment or the test-suite might therefore make it impossible to check-in code.

Comment: OK. So what about make it a standard and give the developer the option to disable this restriction when needed?

Comment: "give the developer the option to disable this restriction when needed": that would be better. But rather than a policing approach it might be better still to educate your developers that checking-in only code that has a unit test-suite and that passes those tests is something worthwhile.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you don't have the ability to work ONLY with great programmers...